contract deployment success in other network but fails in amoy testnet
I try to deploy contract in amoy testnet, but it failed. I have plenty of balance, and had no problem with provider.
This is my failed transaction (https://amoy.polygonscan.com/tx/0x8a29b6c6cd0d2c25639c2a445b2fb3b263247254c9b96567a336be69a5eab99d)
with exacatly same code, the contract deployment succeeded in sepolia testnet.
This is my succeeded transaction(https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xd3291382fa1e27a703e441fab16d94b5861877bd5de32e694fde63a61a29c83d)
I also found out that when I try to deploy contract in remixIDE, it warns that transaction will reverted in amoy. but it doesn't warn in sepolia testnet or polygon mainnet.
I have two questions

how can contract address comes out even if transaction fails?
why does same contract deployment fails in amoy but success in sepolia? I try deploying in local and remix, but the results were all same.


It`s hard to tell like this but my guess would be that some of the addresses that might work and be valid on one network might not be on another.
https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/polygon-amoy/0x8a29b6c6cd0d2c25639c2a445b2fb3b263247254c9b96567a336be69a5eab99d
It fails on a contract and method.
this is the address where it failed.
0x000000000000aaeb6d7670e522a718067333cd4e calling the register and subscribe.

The address or your contract can be determined by the bytecode. This is why it is possible to have the same address on different network

Since you pass addresses as argument to your method that fails. I suspect the address of a contract might exist on some chain and be the same but maybe not all chains.


